# VirtualBox Unable to mount share folder with RW option

Tags: virtualbox

I have a Windows 10 + VirtualBox Ubuntu set up. I want to create a shared folder so I can edit files in both OSes. Using the virtual box native "share folder" configuration does not allow me to edit host files.

I eventually realized I need to mount with RW, but when I run the mount command, it will error

```
mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such file or directory
```

What I tried:

```
sudo mount.vboxsf -o remount,rw umask=022,gid=1000,uid=1000,dmode=777,dmask=000 aaa /media/sf_aaa
```

This command runs fine without the RW option.

Another odd thing is, if I create a file in the share folder from guest OS, and Host OS edits it, guest will no longer to be able to edit the same file again.

What am I doing wrong here?

ps: the user is already in vboxsf group.

Comment: Using the shared folders functionality from the Guest Additions allows either the host or guest to edit documents in the shared folders, if access is set to Full.  I suggest you concentrate your efforts on setting up this built-in functionality to work properly. (Note - I only have Linux hosts, so this comment may not apply to a Windows host, although ISTR from when I had actual Windows PCs, this did work)

Comment: Are the guest additions installed on the Windows end?